# LInux error: Unmet Dependencies

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ubuntu

Error while installing ipython :

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libnss3 : Breaks: libnss3:i386 (!= 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 is installed
 libnss3:i386 : Breaks: libnss3 (!= 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 is installed
 libnss3-nssdb : Depends: libnss3 (= 2:3.23-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) but 2:3.19.2.1-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I am having trouble while executing commands like :

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install ipython
```

any help will be appericiable

Answer (score 0):

You have missing dependencies. You need to execute

```
apt-get -f install
```

as the output tells you to do.

Comment: I've executed it but it is still not working and moreover after executing the

    apt-get -f install 

I am getting following line at the end :

    E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)